# Como retornar um atributo de um classe baseado no mínimo e máximo de outros atributos do array?

Tags: python, array, classes

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso percorrer o vetor de objetos e retornar o nome da empresa que possuir menor quantidade de funcionários e o nome da empresa que possuir maior capital.

Sei que há os comandos de min() e max() para as listas. Mas como retornar o nome da empresa que corresponde ao atributo de valor mínimo e máximo?

```
class Empresa:
    def __init__(self,nome,capital,nFuncionarios):
        self.nome = nome
        self.capital = capital
        self.nFuncionarios = nFuncionarios

class EmpresaDemo():
    empresa = Empresa(['Teste Corporation','Teste Ltda','Teste & Cia','Teste transportes','Teste Tech'],[1000000,900700,505000,30022,405045],[777,30,40,22,1])
```

```
min(empresa.nFuncionarios) # Me retorna apenas o item que possui valor mínimo.
max(empresa.capital) # Me retorna apenas o item que possui valor máximo.
```

Answer (score -2):

A sua modelagem não te ajudará muito a diferenciar um elemento do outro, todos são elementos dentro de uma lista, é possível usar o atributo `index()` para descobrir qual a posição do valor que você recebeu e assim descobrir as outras informações mas a informação continuará dissociada.

Eu recomendaria uma abordagem onde a informação fica mais fácil de ser trabalhada:

```py
class Empresa:
    def __init__(self, nome, capital, n_func):
        self.nome = nome
        self.capital = capital
        self.n_func = n_func

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


dados_empresas = (
    ("Teste Corporation", 777, 1000000),
    ("Teste Ltda", 30, 900700),
    ("Teste & Cia", 505000, 40),
    ("Teste transportes", 22, 30022),
    ("Teste Tech", 1, 405045),
)

empresas = [Empresa(*i) for i in dados_empresas]
```

Os dados das empresas são inseridos em uma lista (ou `array`) contendo a classe que você já tinha definido, ficando um objeto por empresa (assim você tem os dados todos juntos).

O método `__str__()` serve para informa à linguagem o que você deseja que seja exibido quando tua classe precisar ser exibida como *string* (no caso eu só exibo o nome da empresa).

Assim é possível usar `max()` e `min()` diretamente...

```
print(max(empresas, key=lambda i: i.capital))
print(min(empresas, key=lambda i: i.n_func))
```

Esta "coisa" com o `lambda` serve para passar às funções os valores que você deseja usar para encontrar os valores máximo e mínimo.

```
Teste & Cia
Teste & Cia
```